# Change the Text of an asp:CheckBox when clicked

Tags: asp.net, javascript, checkbox

How can I change the Text for a CheckBox without a postback?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Open" />
```

I would like to toggle the Text to read "Open" or "Closed" when the CheckBox is clicked on the client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function changeCheckboxText(checkbox)
{
  if (checkbox.checked)
    checkbox.nextSibling.innerHTML = 'on text';
  else
    checkbox.nextSibling.innerHTML = 'off text';
}
```

called as:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkTest" onclick="changeCheckboxText(this);" />
```

Just FYI, it's usually bad practice to change the text of the checkbox label because it tends to confuse the user.

Comment: This is probably the best bet. ASP.NET controls do not provide an easy way to get the `id` attribute, so you typically can't just use `$('#someid'). I try to avoid `onclick` attributes, but in this case this is the easiest way.

Comment: It would have been OK to use <%=chkTest.ClientID%> with  document.getElementById() (or $(#'<%=chkText.ClientID %>') if using JQuery), however, the label that the checkbox control emits doesn't have an ID, but you're pretty much guaranteed it will be right after the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested to use a framework javascript like jQuery, i propose a solution ilke this:

```
$("input[id$=CheckBox1]").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) { 
        $(this).next("label:first").text("Open");
    }
    else {
        $(this).next("label:first").text("Close");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

3 Easy Options

Use JavaScript to change the text client side- By Registering the Event in the .CS class like so:

```
CheckBox1.Attributes.Add("JavaScipt")
```

Use an HTML Checkbox with [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Or put in an an [Ajax Update Panel](http://www.asp.net/ajax/)

[Some AJax starter Videos](http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/)

Comment: The first option won't work. input[type=checkbox] don't have text attributes.

Comment: My bad it does create a label with a "for" attribute that I thought was rendered into a change event on the checkbox to the label however I was mistaken