# Checkbox to Control Button Enabled Property - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I would like to know how I can control the 'Enabled' property of a button based on the 'checked' value of a checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnableButton" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnLoadForm" runat="server" />
```

I can do this very easily on the server side - but I require this to be done on client side only, meaning JavaScript. Would the OnCheckedChanged attribute allow me to call some JavaScript to do this....or is it strictly for calling a handler in the code-behind?

Just to clarify, when the checkbox is checked, the button is enabled... when the checkbox is unchecked the button is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkButt(obj) {
    document.getElementById('<%=btnLoadForm.ClientID%>').disabled = !obj.checked;
}
</script>
```

Web Controls:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnableButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="checkButt(this);" />
<asp:Button ID="btnLoadForm" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use here [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(VS.71).aspx) attribute so you can get the control on client side via javascript using `document.getElementById` or `document.forms[0].elements[clientID]`.

```
function enableButton() {

$get('<%= btnLoadForm.ClientID %>').disabled = !$get('<%= chkEnableButton.ClientID %>').checked;

}

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnableButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="enableButton()" />
```

Comment: It might be cleaner to use the `$get` shortcut there. See http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ClientReference/Global/GetShortCutMethod.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429937/change-the-text-of-an-aspcheckbox-when-clicked) might give you a hint of how to do this. In your situation however, instead of changing the text of the `Checkbox`, find the `Button` control on your page and change it's `disabled` property.