# Change button's enabled property via checkbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I tried this JavaScript but it doesn't work - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636268/checkbox-to-control-button-enabled-property-asp-net)

I need to change the button's enabled property to true when the checkbox is checked and to false when it isn't. This is my code:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAcceptAgreement" runat="server" OnClientClick="acceptAgreement(this)" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblUserAgreement" runat="server" Text="I accept the " />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlUserAgreement" runat="server" Text="User Agreement" NavigateUrl="Help/UserAgreement.aspx" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Text="Register"  />
  </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function acceptAgreement(obj) {
    document.getElementById('<%=btnRegister.ClientID%>').disabled = !obj.checked;
  }
</script>
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive, you have `Obj` and `obj` in your function, they must match :)

To fix, change your function to this:

```
function acceptAgreement(obj) {
  document.getElementById('<%=btnRegister.ClientID%>').disabled = !obj.checked;
}
```

Comment: @Ivan - What's not working, it's not toggling, it's not initially disabled, javascript error...other?

Comment: the button is enabled all the time

Comment: @Ivan - Are you getting a javascript error?  If not, can you post the rendered markup that your page is outputting?

Comment: It worked! :) I had to change OnClientClick="acceptAgreement(this)" to OnClick="acceptAgreement(this)" and set the button enabled property to false. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function acceptAgreement(id){ // where id is check box id
  var check = document.getElementById(id).checked
  document.getElementById('btnRegister').disabled = !check
}
```

Comment: where `"master"` is `id`, hey?

Answer (score 0):

since you have these buttons and checkbox running at server why dont you handle the enabling and disabling with the server code behind. Also which programming language are you using for the codebehind c# example

```
            protected void cbAcceptAgreement_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             btnRegister.Enabled = cbAcceptAgreement.Checked;
        }
```

Page part

```
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAcceptAgreement" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
        oncheckedchanged="cbAcceptAgreement_CheckedChanged" />
```

lemme know if this worked for you Ivan

changed to autopostback = true for the chekcbox hopefully that will help

Comment: that's a terrible idea. doing this clientside will give much better performance, much better user experience, and with much less code (hitting the server for this would require an ajax/updatepanel implementation)

Comment: I use C#. I've been searching for a code behind solution, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: ok its a simple register it doesnt get used terribly often and I dont know why you would HAVE to do it client side. That may be the case only in a few examples such as mobile web browsing where u wouldnt want to wait for the server but I think in the scope of this question client side would be fine. Otherwise WHY even HAVE a client side

Comment: also what if javascript is disabled that would make the answer using javascript moot

Comment: @Laurence Burke - If javascript is disabled, your postback won't fire either, not off a checkbox :)

Comment: well then will my answer work?? tell me that at least. with javascript enabled

Comment: The problem is that Visual Studio can't find .IsChecked event

Comment: @Laurence - **If** this was a good idea, at least remove the fluff :) `btnRegister.Enabled = cbAcceptAgreement.Checked;`